# 200 stream not found netstream.play.streamnotfound clip

Tags: video-streaming, flash, flv, flvplayer

I got streaming error on this site  http://68.233.16.160/news/7

says something like

```
200 stream not found netstream.play.streamnotfound clip
```

I've been looking for this error for a week allready, the most common thing for this error is the **mime type** enabled on the server, the client support of railsplayground host told me that they have flv mime type enabled on the server.

Here is the answer I got from the sysadmin on my ticket about this problem:

> The flv mime type is enabled on the server and I've installed the flv
>   module for apache and ffmpeg. However it still throwing the "200
>   stream not found netstream.play.streamnotfound" error. Is there any
>   module/software to be installed on the server to make it work so that
>   we can install it for you. Regards,
>
> Simon Rajan Level II System Administrator

the thing is I dont't really know if I need any other module/software for this to make it work.
I have the same app on other host that's working just fine:

http://ec2-107-22-183-238.compute-1.amazonaws.com/news/1

the same source code on both hosts.. why do I get this error?

btw, I use flowplayer if this will help somehow to get the sollution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded another flv from youtube and loaded it to my web app and it worked. There was something with the file itself. After I converted the the avi to flv again and loaded it up it worked ok.

Comment: I found that if a file have space in name like "ice age 4.flv" then flowplayer cannot play the file and show this error. stream not found netstream.play.streamnotfound

Comment: didn't tried it, my file was in one name like  videoname.flv. Thank you anyway for your reply may be it will help someone. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue with flowplayer - if you are using the Jomsocial module on Joomla for example, turn off the psuedo streaming option. See if your module set up has something similar

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not using Jomsocial module on Joomla. Anyway the problem was with a corrupt flv file type. I just downloaded  another flv from youtube and loaded it to my web app and it worked..

Answer (score 0):

I had the 200 stream not found error on my local intranet. HTML in Internet Explorer wants to load the file from the other machine into flowplayer and that fails.

Inspecting the URL, everything looks fine and the file is there. Until I realized the url was not fine. Its format was "file://myServer/serverpath/file.flv", however, that should be "file:////myServer/serverpath/file.flv" because the format is:

```
"file://" (the protocol) + "//myServer" (server root) + "/serverpath/file.flv".
```

I now update the path that Internet Explorer makes of it by inserting "//"

(IE10, Windows 7, Flash 11.9, flowplayer-3.1.4.js)